# Jquery Google Drive Post name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-drive-api

I'm trying to post a new file to google drive via jquery.ajax. I have it posting a file to google, however the file is named "Untitled", and my json information is in the file, rather than changing the filename. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            var testUpload = {
                'title': 'testupload',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
            }
            var contentType = "text/plain";
            var multipartRequestBody =
                delimiter +
                'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                JSON.stringify(testUpload) +
                delimiter +
                'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                '\r\n' +
                "testing this stuff" +
                close_delim;    
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                },
                data: testUpload,
                //data: multipartRequestBody,
                //title: 'json',
                //cache: false,
                contentType: contentType,
                //processData: true,
                //type: 'POST',
            });
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877817/file-upload-via-rest-v3-appears-as-untitled/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload via REST v3 appears as "Untitled"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877817/file-upload-via-rest-v3-appears-as-untitled)